# Accessing colors from colors.xml in an intArrayOf

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, colors

I have a Kotlin object that should take a parameter of an array of colors. These colors are defined in `colors.xml`.

**Object:**

```
class Teams(teamName:String, teamColors:IntArray){
    var teamName = ""
    var teamColors = intArrayOf(R.color.ElectricBlue, R.color.FireRed)
    init {
        this.teamName = teamName
        this.teamColors = teamColors
    }
}
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="ElectricBlue">#0089ff</color>
    <color name="FireRed">#d22826</color>
    <!-- 20 more... -->
</resources>
```

Whenever I try accessing the colors in the actual views, all colors just show up as a gray color with around 40% alpha.

```
teamColorGradient.colors = intArrayOf(R.color.ForestGreen, R.color.LightningYellow)
```

How can I initialize my Teams object so that it takes an array of colors that are defined in `colors.xml`?

Comment: "Whenever I try accessing the colors in the actual views" -- how are you doing that? Remember that these are resource IDs, not colors -- you need to call `getColor()` on a `Resources` object to get the actual color.

Comment: `R.color` is just resource identifier. You need to resolve that value against app context, for example using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId)`.

Comment: @Pawel that worked perfect. Thanks. Still getting the hang of navigating around Android! Mark that as your answer and I'll accept it.